# How to show float if the user inputs a digit with a decimal and int if the user inputs a whole number using function overloading

Tags: c++

I am currently studying C++ by watching [bucky's C++ tutorial](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=16&number=30).

In the tutorial he shows how to use function overloading
but the variables values of `a` and `b` are fixed in his tutorial video. 
I'm wondering what happens if the user needs to input something (decimal or whole number)
and how to make the program identify whether the input data is an int or an float.

here is the code in the tutorial video:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printnumber(int x){
    cout << "I am printing an integer " <<x << endl;
}

void printnumber(float x){
    cout << "I am printing an float: " << x << endl;
}


int main(){

    int a = 54;
    float b= 32.4896;

    printnumber(a);
    printnumber(b);

}
```

While here is the code I created:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a;
float b;

void printnumber(int x){
    cout << "I am printing an integer " <<x << endl;
}

void printnumber(float x){
    cout << "I am printing an float: " << x << endl;
}


int main(){

    cout << "enter a whole number or a number with decimal: ";
    cin >> ; //what will i put here?

    printnumber(a);
    printnumber(b);

}
```

Comment: User can enter anything, even just a string. You should control user input, check whether it is convertible to desired type, and if so use that value for your variable. Your variable should be strict typed. Example only shows that in a particular case you can change output depending on type of the variable. You can ask user to enter int number first and then float. Then print both variables with your function.

Answer (score 2):

This is not as trivial as one would think. One way could be to read the input as a string, and see if the string contains a decimal-point (which would cause problems on locales where the decimal-point is a comma instead).

Another solution is to read as a string, then try to [convert it to a floating point value](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), and if that fails then [convert it to an integer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

I would recommend the last method.

---

Or for simplicity's sake, just instruct the user to input an integer followed by a floating point value:

```
int a;
std::cout << "Enter an integer value: ";
std::cin >> a;

float b;
std::cout << "Enter a floating point value: ";
std::cin >> b;
```

Then hope that the user actually enters correct values.

Comment: hmm.. how about the user needs to input only one time?

Comment: @user3490590 If you want two numbers, then you can't have a single input. You can have a single input *statement* though: `std::cin >> a >> b`. It's one statement, but two inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a `std::string` back from `cin` which you will need to convert to the appropriate type once you detect if it has a dot or not.

```
std::string user_input;

cout << "enter a whole number or a number with decimal: ";
cin >> user_input;

if(user_input.find('.') != std::string::npos){
  // we found a float (probably)
  // uses boost library to make stuff easier
  printNumber(boost::lexical_cast<float>(user_input));
}else{
  printNumber(boost::lexical_cast<int>(user_input));
}
```

instead of `boost::lexical_cast` you can also use `std::stringstream`

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << user_input;
if(user_input.find('.') != std::string::npos){
  // we found a float (probably)
  float f;
  ss >> f;
  printNumber(f);
}else{
  int i;
  ss >> i;
  printNumber(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not get the data until runtime, so you can't know the type at compile time, which is when the function overload is determined.  Thus, you need to make some decision at runtime.

I suggest you look up my most favorite C++ book of all time, *Advanced C++ Programming Styles and Idioms* by Jim Coplien.  Pay careful attention to the letter/envelop idiom, which describes how to accomplish what you want.

It may be overkill for this simple example, but it's worth learning since you are hunting for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Joachim is right that this isn’t trivial. The “proper” way to do this is to use a parser.

Writing such a parser isn’t too hard – it just needs to check that the number is in the right format, by trying to read it as either type and retrying if it doesn’t work. A “cleaner” solution is to use a formal parsing framework such as [Boost.Spirit.Qi](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html).

Here’s a straightforward (but somewhat convoluted) solution:

```
int main() {
    std::string value;
    std::cin >> value;

    std::size_t end;
    int intval = std::stoi(value, &end);
    if (end == value.size())
        printnumber(intval);
    else
        printnumber(std::stof(value));
}
```

This checks that [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) converted the *whole* string rather than just parts of it.

Notice that this solution is not very robust since it does no proper error checking. In a real application I would strongly recommend going the Boost.Qi way because it makes the code simpler and more robust, but it requires some deeper C++ knowledge.

For reference, the “proper” solution using a parsing framework would look something like this:

```
struct printer : boost::static_visitor<void> {
    template <typename T>
    void operator ()(T const& value) const { printnumber(value); }
};

int main() {
    std::string value;
    std::cin >> value;

    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    auto begin = std::begin(value);
    auto const end = std::end(value);
    boost::variant<int, float> result;
    bool success = qi::parse(begin, end, (qi::int_ >> !qi::lit('.')) | qi::float_, result);
    if (not success or begin != end)
        std::cerr << "Something went wrong\n";
    else
        apply_visitor(printer{}, result);
}
```