# How to check if the input taken by the user doesn't contain decimal?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am a newbie to C++. I have a situation where the input integer is taken from the user. However, I need to check if the user enters a decimal value. How do I check this?

I have tried `cin.good()`, `cin.fail()` but they are detecting only non-digit entries and not decimal numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  int x;
  cout << "Enter an integer: " << endl;
  cin >> x;

  if (cin.good()) {
    cout << "input is an integer" << endl;
  }
  else 
    cout << "input is not an integer" << endl;
}
```

Here's my output:

1.

```
Enter an integer: 
1.2
input is an integer
```

2.

```
Enter an integer: 
a
input is not an integer
```

Comment: Can't you just check if the input is equal to its floor ?

Comment: why not read it as a float and check it for decimal and then cast it to integer?

Comment: for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858398/how-to-show-float-if-the-user-inputs-a-digit-with-a-decimal-and-int-if-the-user

Comment: you can simply use casting http://i.imgur.com/PKB3FB1.png

Comment: @MohamedSlama: Sure, if correctness is not one of your primary goals.

Comment: @Benoit, OutofRange thank you! My bad, I never thought of that! By the way, aren't cin.good() and cin.fail() used for the same purpose,i.e to check if the user input matches/is different from the datatype of the variable? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
float x = 4.2;
if (x == (int) x)
{
    // int
}
else
{
    // not int
}
```

Comment: Consider using [`std::floor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor) instead of the C-style cast, or if you _really_ want to cast use `static_cast` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::isdigit` for checking your string input next way.

```
  bool is_numeric(const std::string& str)
  {
     std::string::const_iterator it = str.begin();
     if (it != str.end() && *it == '-') ++it;
     if (it == str.end()) return false;
     while (it != str.end() && std::isdigit(*it)) ++it;
     return it == str.end();
  }
```

It's not hard to change it to work with floating points, if needs, but that function will exactly checks what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You receive the input as an `int` from `cin` and hence any float entered would already be truncated by the time you get your hands on it.  You should receive it as a `float` or a `string` to decide on the validity of the input.

Removed the earlier answer since it went down the slippery route of manually parsing the input which is unnecessary and error-prone.  The standard library already has multiple ways to check if an input is a valid number.  Two ways that I know: C++ streams and the C library function `strtof`.  Here's an example using the latter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

bool is_int(float f) {
    return std::floor(f) == f;
}    

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    char *e = nullptr;
    char const *str = input.c_str();
    float const f = strtof(str, &e);
    // no conversion was performed or was stopped as disallowed
    // characters were encountered: Not A Number
    if ((e == str) || (*e != '\0'))
        std::cout << "NAN";
    else if ((f == HUGE_VALF) || !std::isfinite(f))
        std::cout << "too large";
    else
        std::cout << (is_int(f) ? "integer" : "non-integer");
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7aba27a45d80d622).

To check if the input is a number, this

```
float f;
cin >> f;
```

is possible too, but it will also accept NANs as valid input e.g. `45dsf` will be converted to `45`.  One has to then check if the conversion happened completely and successfully by checking the `fail` and `eof` bits of the stream.

#### See also

- [Checking if float is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5796983/183120)
- [C++ IsFloat function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/447206/183120)
- [How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5290089/183120)

Comment: `Enter an integer:` - `a` - `input is an integer`

Comment: Of course, further validations are needed, the answer was for what the question specifically asked for: "that the input doesn't contain a decimal". A real-world program should be doing lot more through checks e.g. digit separators.

Comment: I didn't make this up. This is sample input from the original question. An answer should be capable of dealing with sample input provided by the OP.

Comment: @legends2k `isNumber` produces UB on empty string and gives [discutable results on some inputs](http://ideone.com/LAhDz0).

Comment: @IIns I don't know your definition of what an answer should be like, but I know that not even giving a solution and pointing to the right direction would do; [see the help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): _Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful._ Giving a 100% correct, working solution in just an answer box is impractical and impossible, we've libraries to do that.

Comment: @Hiura So, what's your point?  Untested code is written for teaching something to give a feel for such things and no one claims it's production quality checked-in code.  Helping the OP will do, completing his/her task isn't need and not encouraged anyways.

Comment: I  see, thanks for your comments, made me learn a few things.